# Partial included using ng-include has been removed, but my console shows a $compile:tpload Failed to load template error

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase

At first, I used ng-include to include a partial html code, but then I changed my mind and removed it completely from my code. Now, for some reason, I'm getting this error message "Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: templates/partials/_aboutMe.html". I wonder what's going on and want to get rid of it but I don't know how.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Something in your code is requesting that template, and it can't find it. You just have to find the part that's including it and remove that.

Comment: @matmo Thanks for your response. Actually, I removed the ng-include directive along with the portion of the code that was requesting that partial, a while ago. I searched around and I don't see where this could be coming from. I even cleared the cache for both, my browser and ionic app. Still not able to get it resolved. Really wondering what I'm missing.

Comment: Do a global search for 'aboutMe.html', probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was the problem! One of my directives was requesting it. @matmo many thanks.